# how can i solve No such token: 'tok_1MtvkRSCQQ84qVMJpmJWQ1OG?

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

when i submit detail for stripe test mode i got this error : Uncaught Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest: No such token: 'tok_1MtvkRSCQQ84qVMJpmJWQ1OG' in E:\xampp

when i put the detail on custom form and after click on submit button I'm facing this error no such a token
i'm using stripe key and publish key from my stripe test mode account

Comment: This needs more context in order to be answerable.  Please share the relevant snippet of your code that shows the API endpoint being used, the parameters being passed, and how you are providing your API key.  Please DO NOT include your actual API keys though.

Comment: so which key will we use? i have publish and secret key on test mode.

Comment: Please address the questions I asked.  What API request are you making? What are the parameters you are passing?